# Permutation Test for mean ratio

Tags: r, permutation-test, ratio, permutation

I am given three vectors of length 11, that represent blood levels of a
hormone measured after placebo, old and new treatment.

```
placebo= c( 9243, 9671, 11792, 13357, 9055, 6290, 12412, 18806, 9245,
            9673, 11796,13412, 9212,6790,12510,19002)
old= c(17649, 12013, 19979, 21816, 13850, 9806, 17208, 29044,
          17653, 12100,20012,21945,13914,10012,17514,29114)
new =c(16449, 14614, 17274, 23798, 12560, 10157, 16570, 26325, 16552,
      14712, 17552, 24012, 12598, 10212, 16789, 26412)
```

The exercise is to determine, whether the mean difference between new and old treatment is as great as the one between old and placebo treatment, by performing a permutation test on their ratio. To be honest, I think this statistic is a bit pointless, but that's what the teacher asked us to do. In order to solve it, i first computed the observed ratio as follows.

```
n<-length(placebo) # sample size

A = new-old
B = old-placebo

ratio.hat<-mean(A)/mean(B)

print(ratio.hat)
```

Afterward, I tried to simulate a p-value through the following procedure.

```
iterations <- 1000


stat <- numeric(iterations)
for (i in 1:iterations) {
  chosen <- sample(1:32,16)
  stat[i] <- mean(c(A,B)[chosen])/mean(c(A,B)[-chosen])
}


hist(stat, xlim = c(-1,6))

ci <- quantile(stat, c(0.025,0.975))

abline(v = ratio.hat, col = "red", lwd = 2)
abline(v = ci, col = "red", lty = c(2,2), lwd = c(2,2))
```

[image: simulated Ci under Ho]

Now, the observed Ratio is outside the CI under H0, so I follow that the A and B are different. Can someone tell me, if this is correct?

Furthermore, I should simulate a CI for the observed ratio A/B, which I tried like this:

```
stat2 <- numeric(iterations)
for (i in 1:iterations) {
  chosen1 <- sample(1:16,16, replace = T)
  chosen2 <- sample(1:16,16, replace = T)
  stat2[i] <- mean(A[chosen1])/mean(B[chosen2])
}

ci2 <- quantile(stat2, c(0.025,0.975))

hist(stat2)
abline(v = ratio.hat, col = "red", lwd = 2)
abline(v = ci2, col = "red", lty = c(2,2), lwd = c(2,2))
```

I conclude, that, thus 1 isn't part of the CI, that A and B are significantly different. Can someone tell me, if that is correct?

Best regards

Comment: Are the observations paired, in the sense that the first observation in each vector corresponds to the same individual, or does it just so happen that each has 11 observations?

Comment: Yes, they are paired. We consider 11 individuals, that each got the 3 treatments.

Comment: Actually you have 16 individuals...otherwise, this looks good to me.

Comment: ah yeah true, 16, thanks.

Comment: The only thing left, is a CI for the ratio A/B. Here I didn't really know, what to do and tried to simulate it like I describe in the edited question.

Comment: That's what I would have done, for what it's worth, but it seems to me this is probably meant to be a one-sided test, so instead of $0.025, 0.975$ for the quantiles, it might be just $0.05$.